# Converting a grunt browserify task to gulp

Tags: gruntjs, reactjs, gulp, browserify

I am trying to convert an old `grunt` task to `gulp`. The task uses `browserify`:

```
browserify: {
    options: {
        transform: [ require('grunt-react').browserify ]
    },
    client: {
        src: ['react/**/*.jsx'],
        dest: 'public/js/browserify/bundle.js'
    }
}
```

I have following plugins loaded in my `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var reactify = require('reactify');
var source = require("vinyl-source-stream");
```

How can I create the same task in `gulp` using `browserify` with `reactify` as a transform?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want something along these lines:

```js
gulp.task('whatever', function () {
  return browserify({
    entries: [...]
  })
    .transform(reactify, { /* opts if any */ })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/browserify'));
});
```

But if you need to glob the entry files, you'll probably also need to pull in a globbing module and use that to generate the list (array) you pass to browserify as entry files.